# Algorithm for determining an algebraic positivity property of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: algorithms, polynomials, computer-algebra

I am considering multivariate polynomials with integer coefficients that can be expressed as sums of products of terms of the form $y_i-z_j$ for positive integers $i$ and $j$. I am trying to find an algorithm to determine if there is a way to express them in terms of these linear factors in such a way that the terms have nonnegative coefficients. I have a conjecture that this is always true for the polynomials that I am considering, and I want to do some extensive testing of it.

For example, my program outputs the following in one case (for reasons of speed, absolutely no simplification is done intermediately; computing the coefficients is at best $\#P$-complete even when the degree of the polynomial is $0$):
$$-2 (y_2 - z_1) (y_1 - z_1) + 2 (y_1 + y_2 - z_1 - z_2) (y_1 + y_2 - z_1 - z_3) - (-(y_2 - z_1) (y_1 - z_1) + (y_1 + y_2 - z_1 - z_2) (y_1 + y_2 - z_1 - z_3))$$
This is not expressed in a positive manner, but there is cancelation you can do to get
$$(y_2-z_1)(y_2-z_3)+(y_1-z_2)(y_1-z_1)+(y_1-z_2)(y_2-z_3)$$
and this would pass the test.

For context, it's considered a hopelessly difficult unsolved problem to determine whether computing the degree $0$ coefficients is in $\#P$, though the problem is known to be in $\mathrm{GapP}^+$.

When I plug this example into Maple and call simplify, I get
$$y_1^2 + (y_2 - z_1 - z_2 - z_3)*y_1 + y_2^2 + (-z_1 - z_2 - z_3)*y_2 + (z_2 + z_3)*z_1 + z_2*z_3$$
which is not really very helpful.

A conjecture that would be easier to check is that, when expanded, the polynomial has nonnegative coefficients in terms of $y_i$ and $-z_j$, but this is not quite the same.

I am really just looking for any algorithm at all; it doesn't have to be fast.

Comment: What is $n$?  Is it the total degree of the polynomial?  Is it the number of variables?  Would it be enough to consider only expressions where the number of terms in each product is at most the total degree of the original polynomial?

Comment: What's the best algorithm you know so far?  I gather this is the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4404782/14578?

Comment: @D.w. $n$ is the rank of the permutation group in the problem. $n=5$ has $120^2$ sets of cases to check. It's not really important to the question so maybe I shouldn't have included it. I asked this question because I can't think of *any* algorithm to do it at all.

Comment: The problem never mentions any permutation group, so I'm not sure what that refers to.  I'm still wondering about the prior question about whether we can limit the number of terms in each product, based on the degree of the original polynomial.

Comment: @D.W. I haven't described the problem that these polynomials come from at all because it's not relevant to the question, so perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned $n=5$. I'm happy to describe what the problem is privately but it would sort of derail the question I think. I can remove the reference to $n$ if needed.

Comment: I suggest removing the n=5, and explaining what limit you have in mind in terms that refer only to what you've defined in the question itself.  How many variables would you have in a typical problem instance?  What would the total degree be in a typical instance?

Comment: @D.W. For $n=5$ (the reference to which I removed) the maximum degree would be $10$ (but I know the degree $10$ polynomials are positive...the lower the degree the harder, sort of). It would be $5$ $y$ variables and $5$ $z$ variables. All degrees between $0$ and $10$ occur. Most common, numerically, would be $5$. Should I include this in the question?

Comment: @D.W. Just saw your edited comment. Yes, it is the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a semi-algorithm.  I don't know if it is a good one.  If your conjecture is true, it always terminates.  In particular, if a solution exists, it will find it; if no solution exists, it will run forever, searching for one.

Let $p(x)$ be the original polynomial; it can be expressed in the form
$$p(x) = \sum_S \alpha_S \prod_{(v,w) \in S} (v-w),$$
where $S$ is a set of pairs $(v,w)$ of variables (here $v$ is some $y_i$ and $w$ is some $z_j$).  Let $q(x)$ be the re-expressed polynomial we are trying to search for.  Let $k$ be an upper bound on the number of terms in the product, which might initially be set to 2.  Then the general form of the non-negative polynomial is
$$q(x) = \sum_S \beta_S \prod_{(v,w) \in S} (v-w),$$
where the sum is over all sets $S$ of pairs, such that $|S|\le k$.  We require that $p(x)=q(x)$ and $\beta_S \ge 0$ for all $S$.  Given the $\alpha$'s, our goal is to find $\beta$'s that satisfy these conditions.

Notice that we can multiply out each product above, putting $p(x)$ into the following form:

$$p(x) = \sum_T \delta_T \prod_{v \in T} v,$$

where $T$ ranges over multisets of variables.  Here $\delta_T$ can be expressed as a linear function of the $\alpha_S$'s.  Since the $\alpha$'s are given, this means we can compute each $\delta_T$ as an explicit constant.  Similarly,

$$q(x) = \sum_T \gamma_T \prod_{v \in T} v,$$

where $\gamma_T$ is a known linear function of the $\beta_S$'s.  $\gamma_T$ is not known, but it is a linear function of the $\beta$ variables.

Finally, since we want to have $p(x) = q(x)$, this means we require $\delta_T = \gamma_T$ for all $T$, which means we equate the known constant $\delta_T$ to the linear function of $\beta$'s that represents $\gamma_T$.  Also, we have the inequality $\beta_S \ge 0$ for all $S$.

Putting it together, this gives us a system of linear equalities and inequalities on the $\beta_S$'s.  We can then use linear programming to check whether there exists a solution to this linear system.  If there exists a solution, then we have found a way to express $p(x)$ in the desired form.

If there is no solution, then we can increase $k$ and try again.  Repeat until we find a solution.  If a solution exists, we will eventually find it.  The complexity will be exponential, as there can be exponentially many $S$'s and $T$'s, but it is something that can be implemented.  However, if no solution exists, this will run forever.

To test your conjecture, as a heuristic, you could set an upper bound on $k$, and then any polynomial where no solution is found up to that value of $k$ is a candidate that might violate the conjecture; and if no such candidate is found, then it increases confidence in your conjecture (but of course does not prove it).

Comment: Thanks! Like I said, any algorithm is better than none. I didn't expect one that ran forever if the conjecture fails, but I can work with that. I expect that the conjecture is true anyway. Unfortunately I have a "day job" that is unrelated to this so I won't be able to test this until this weekend.

Comment: I think this actually can be made to always terminate. The polynomials are homogeneous, so I think there's a maximum "generic polynomial."

Comment: That would be $131,128,140$ terms for degree $10$ in $5$ pairs of variables. Not sure how many variables are feasible for linear programming, but I'm guessing that's not it. Can probably be refined. Anyway, I think this will work. Thanks.

Comment: I've thought about your answer all day and I think the way to go is as follows: Find the monomials in the $y$ variables when you $0$ out the $z$ variables and vice versa, then pair these up in all possible ways to get the terms on which to optimize. I think there should be few enough that it will be feasible.

Comment: @MattSamuel, a generalization of that is to pick a subset of monomials $T$ and equate their coefficients.  This gives a subset of the equalities in the full linear system.  If the full linear system is over-constrained, it might be sufficient to pick a subset of equalities, search for a solution to the subsystem, and test whether it happens to give you a solution to the full system (if it doesn't, then the results are inconclusive and have to increase the number of monomials in your subset).

Comment: Regarding your latest comment, is this for the purpose of reducing the amount of computation that's required? I'm running a preliminary test to just check if the coefficients are positive in terms of the $y$ and $-z$ variables to warm up.

Comment: @MattSamuel, yes, only for purposes of reducing the amount of calculation, since you mentioned the LP system might be too large (which I agree with).

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that the condition holds if and only if it has nonnegative coefficients in terms of $y_i$ and $-z_j$, given the fact that it is already expressible as a polynomial in the terms $y_i-z_j$. Need to find an example that contradicts that before I put in the work of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I think I can prove it. All I need to do is prove that it has nonnegative coefficients in terms of $y_i$ and $-z_j$. I'll accept your answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I'm no longer sure it's true if it only has nonnegative coefficients, but I did use this linear optimization method to verify the conjecture for $n=5$. Brute force worked for degree $2$, then I had to get more and more clever until finally I finished with degree $6$, which is sufficient because I know positive formulas for the degree $7$, $8$, $9$, and $10$ polynomials. If I'm going to approach $n=6$ I need to get a bit more clever. Testing each degree took $2$ hours, and there are $100$ times more cases for $n=6$, and I would have to test up to degree $11$.

Comment: I was running $n=6$, prepared for it to take 20 days, until it hit a case with $89295$ base monomials, so it ended up using gigabytes of memory and the operating system killed it. Like I said, testing $n=5$ was breaking new ground, so it's better than what I had before (before I tested the cases my formula doesn't cover for $n=4$ by hand, because there were only $8$. Not very compelling evidence).

Comment: Looks like $n=6$ is going to work. I decided to write a program to display the coefficients with the results of the optimization to make it clear they are nonnegative in this sense, only to discover the optimizer was finding coefficients that were non-integers. I wanted integers, so I switched it to integer optimization and it's many times faster and uses a lot less memory. It's going to take a little over a day at this rate, not bad at all.

Comment: Your idea of only picking some of the monomials doesn't really work, almost all of them are needed. However, I can set any single one of the variables to $0$ without changing the calculation. I know the $z$ variables are "bottom heavy" from the theory and the variable that probably occurs the most often is $z_1$, so I set that to $0$ and that reduces the dimension quite a bit. I asked another question about optimizing it and posted working code, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288222/python-integer-optimization-with-pulp-involving-polynomials-that-i-think-can-be . Thanks again.